# Remove character from column Pandas. Str.replace() not working

Tags: python, string, pandas, str-replace

The following is the column that I am working with

```
Impressions
104
390
1,548
5,850
1,652
6,240
2,684
10,140
7,431
28,080
7,224
27,300
33845
29615
55000
71922
19038
29615
25384
31730
27693
24231
45000
58847
15577
24231
20769
25962
```

I am trying to remove the "," from the rows the strings that contain them. I used the following code to do so:

```
Fw_Queue_Clean['Impressions']= Fw_Queue_Clean['Impressions'].str.replace(',','')
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following result.

```
Impressions
104
390
1548
5850
1652
6240
2684
10140
7431
28080
7224
27300
```

I do not know why some of the data is dropping off after I run that line of code. Could you please offer suggestions as to how I may avoid this and an explanation as to why this is happening? I am fairly new to python and am having trouble figuring this one out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I copied your data and ran your code and it worked for me. Are you sure the output displaying your dataframe is not just truncated?

Comment: Try to print the length of the column, not the column itself. Toby may be right that it is truncating the column.

Comment: @TobyPetty - Thanks for responding! I'm not sure, I don't think so. I'm exporting my data with the following code Fw_Queue_Clean.to_csv(r'C:\Users\j.cordoba\Desktop\Import_File_Jan_01222020(test5).csv',index=False).

Comment: @Josh even then its working

Comment: Wth is going on then! haha

Comment: Do you have any other steps between the code you posted and the `to_csv` call?

Comment: Nope.. I'm exporting to a csv right after the str.replace() code

Comment: Got it to work!.... I took the suggestion given by the person that submitted the answer (Fw_Queue_Clean['Impressions'] = Fw_Queue_Clean['Impressions'].astype(str)). When I run that right before the str.replace() the column remains intact. Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with that before:

```
Fw_Queue_Clean['Impressions'].astype(str)
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much. Any idea as to why it was happening?

Comment: I'm not sure why it happened, maybe by checking Fw_Queue_Clean.dtypes if it's not recognized as a specific type...